# Unable to get any data from yellowpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, http-proxy

I've written a script in python in combination with requests along with using proxies to get the name of different coffee shops from yellowpage australia. Never worked with proxies, though. I tried several times to get response from that page. But, unable to have that. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Here is what I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.session() as session:
    session.headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    page = session.get('https://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=coffee+shop&locationClue=all+states&lat=&lon=&selectedViewMode=list',
        proxies={'http': 'http://localhost:8000', 'http': '169.50.87.252:80'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".listing-name"):
        print(item.text)
```

Btw, upon execution it neither fetches any data nor throws any error.